# Show point labels next to them in FreeCAD

Tags: python, python-2.7, freecad

I want to create some points in FreeCAD and have their labels displayed next to them. My final goal is to implement [this feature request](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/OpenFOAM-plus/issues/980) I placed in OpenFOAM repo.

I tried creating some points in draft workbench and label them with:

```
App.newDocument("test")
Gui.activateWorkbench("DraftWorkbench")
import Draft

point00=Draft.makePoint(0.0,0.0,0.0)
point00.Label = "0"

point01=Draft.makePoint(1.0,0.0,0.0)
point01.Label = "1"

point03=Draft.makePoint(0.0,1.0,0.0)
point03.Label = "2"
```

Now from [here](https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?t=6218) if I add the code blow:

```
a=App.ActiveDocument.addObject("App::AnnotationLabel","Annotation")
a.LabelText=["0"]
```

it will label the first point:

> [image]

How can I do the same for all of the points I create automatically? my goal is to have some points with labels shown next to them. preferably to have a function that takes x,y,z and label and show the point automatically with the label next to it.

**P.S.** A summary of this effort can be found in [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/9ef9975d31bb01fa2bb88b6db7e0bda9).

Comment: hi, you might create a special python feature object with all required properties. Then write a routine in `execute` method define your visualization logic
```
my_point  = FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.addObject('Part::FeaturePython', name)

Comment: What problems did you find while trying to write such a function?

Comment: @ArtemZhukov would you please elaborate?

Comment: @Goyo I can only label one point. when I try to label the next it removes the first label.

Comment: It might be a bug in FreeCAD or that you are doing it wrong. Hard to tell without looking at your actual code.

Comment: @Goyo it doesn't have to be the way I did it. Any other solution which labels the points would do.

Comment: Sorry for scatered reply, not enough time:) I was suggesting to create a separate python feature object which will realize your custom logic. Something like here:

```
my_point  = FreeCAD.ActiveDocument.addObject('Part::FeaturePython', name)
MyPoint(my_point)

class MyPoint(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        """Initialize properties."""
         obj.addProperty("App::AnnotationLabel","Y")
         obj.addProperty("App::AnnotationLabel","Y")
         obj.addProperty("App::AnnotationLabel","Z")
```

Comment: Then add a view provider to it and create a Factory which creates your points in any coordinate

Comment: @ArtemZhukov thanks for the suggestions. I will try to understand this, but in any case if you had some time to post it in a response it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One temporary solution is to use text. if `vertices` is a list of tuples `(xi, yi, zi)` then:

```
for vertexNum, vertex in enumerate(vertices):
    p=Draft.makePoint(vertex[0],vertex[1],vertex[2])
    p.Label=str(vertexNum)
    Draft.makeText([str(vertexNum)],point=FreeCAD.Vector(vertex[0],vertex[1],vertex[2]))
```