# Python-Regular expressions: extract a list of tuples after a keyword from a text file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, openfoam, freecad

I want to implement a simplified version of what I have suggested [here](https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=30426&p=251815#p251799) to import some vertices from an OpenFOAM `blockMeshDict` file and then [visualize them with FreeCAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953163/show-point-labels-next-to-them-in-freecad).

the part of the file I'm interested in is a list of tuples `(xi yi zi)`s of floats, between parentheses after the `vertices` keyword. the file looks like this:

```
vertices
(
    (1 2 3)
    (3 4 5)
    ...
)
```

I'm able to read the file from the same folder as the python script with:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
with open("blockMeshDict", "r") as f:
    s=f.read()
```

But then when I try to extract the content between the parentheses after the `vertices` with:

```
import re
r1=re.search(r'vertices\n\((.*?)\)', s)
print r1.group(1)
```

I get the error:

> type 'exceptions.IndexError: no such group

and I don't know how to solve it. What I want to have in the end is a list of tuples like `[(x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2)...]` I would appreciate it if you could help me know how I can implement this in Python 2.7.

**P.S.** A summary of this effort can be found in [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/9ef9975d31bb01fa2bb88b6db7e0bda9)

Comment: add a `re.DOTALL` as in `r1=re.search(r'vertices\n\((.*?)\)', s, re.DOTALL)`.

Comment: you may need to use `re.findall` if you want all results stored as a list.

Comment: @Tushortz thanks It now prints the first tuple like `(1,2,3`!

Comment: @Tushortz I tried `findAll` with `print r1` now it gives `['\n(1 2 3']`

Comment: `r1=re.findall(r'(?:vertices\s+)?(\([\w\,]+\))', s, re.DOTALL)`

Comment: Some questions: Can you have multiple "vertices" structures? Can you have other structures (named different) with tuples inside?

Comment: there can be the term in comments but only one vertices is acceptable. the first one should be ok. there are other structures in the middle of `(...)`

Comment: @Julio [here](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/v6-blockmesh/) the syntax of a `blockMeshDict` file.

Comment: And can there be other structures different to "vertices" at the same level? For example `vertices { some_tuplies } --newline-- someotherthing { some_tuples }`

Comment: @Julio ideally no. I don't think so. you may use [this](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/blob/master/tutorials/basic/scalarTransportFoam/pitzDaily/system/blockMeshDict) `blockMeshDict` file as test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the main regex to find the outter structure: `\bvertices\s*\((\s*(?:\([^)]+\)\s*)+)\)`

Before that, we will remove all the comments.

And then an extra regex to extract all content inside the vertices structure: `\([^)]+\)`

See demo [here](https://ideone.com/6c1ry1).

The code:

```
import re

test_str = """
/*--------------------------------*- C++ -*----------------------------------*\
| =========                 |                                                 |
| \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox           |
|  \\    /   O peration     | Version:  5                                     |
|   \\  /    A nd           | Web:      www.OpenFOAM.org                      |
|    \\/     M anipulation  |                                                 |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
FoamFile
{
    version     2.0;
    format      ascii;
    class       dictionary;
    object      blockMeshDict;
}
// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

convertToMeters 0.001;

vertices
(
    (-20.6 0 -0.5)
    (-20.6 25.4 -0.5)  /* Some comment */
    (0 -25.4 -0.5)
    (0 0 -0.5)
    (0 25.4 -0.5)
    (206 -25.4 -0.5)
    (206 0 -0.5)
    (206 25.4 -0.5)
    (290 -16.6 -0.5)
    (290 0 -0.5)
    (290 16.6 -0.5)

    (-20.6 0 0.5)
    (-20.6 25.4 0.5)
    (0 -25.4 0.5)
    (0 0 0.5)
    (0 25.4 0.5)
    (206 -25.4 0.5)
    (206 0 0.5)
    (206 25.4 0.5)
    (290 -16.6 0.5)
    (290 0 0.5)
    (290 16.6 0.5)
  /*(1 2 3 4)*/ // Commented tuple
  //(1 2 3 4)
);

/* vertices commented
vertices
(
    (-20.6 0 -0.5)
    (-20.6 25.4 -0.5)
    (0 -25.4 -0.5)
    (0 0 -0.5)
    (0 25.4 -0.5)
    (206 -25.4 -0.5)
    (206 0 -0.5)
    (206 25.4 -0.5)
    (290 -16.6 -0.5)
    (290 0 -0.5)
    (290 16.6 -0.5)
)
*/

negY
(
    (2 4 1)
    (1 3 0.3)
);

posY
(
    (1 4 2)
    (2 3 4)
    (2 4 0.25)
);

posYR
(
    (2 1 1)
    (1 1 0.25)
);


blocks
(
    hex (0 3 4 1 11 14 15 12)
    (18 30 1)
    simpleGrading (0.5 $posY 1)

    hex (2 5 6 3 13 16 17 14)
    (180 27 1)
    edgeGrading (4 4 4 4 $negY 1 1 $negY 1 1 1 1)

    hex (3 6 7 4 14 17 18 15)
    (180 30 1)
    edgeGrading (4 4 4 4 $posY $posYR $posYR $posY 1 1 1 1)

    hex (5 8 9 6 16 19 20 17)
    (25 27 1)
    simpleGrading (2.5 1 1)

    hex (6 9 10 7 17 20 21 18)
    (25 30 1)
    simpleGrading (2.5 $posYR 1)
);

edges
(
);

boundary
(
    inlet
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (0 1 12 11)
        );
    }
    outlet
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (8 9 20 19)
            (9 10 21 20)
        );
    }
    upperWall
    {
        type wall;
        faces
        (
            (1 4 15 12)
            (4 7 18 15)
            (7 10 21 18)
        );
    }
    lowerWall
    {
        type wall;
        faces
        (
            (0 3 14 11)
            (3 2 13 14)
            (2 5 16 13)
            (5 8 19 16)
        );
    }
    frontAndBack
    {
        type empty;
        faces
        (
            (0 3 4 1)
            (2 5 6 3)
            (3 6 7 4)
            (5 8 9 6)
            (6 9 10 7)
            (11 14 15 12)
            (13 16 17 14)
            (14 17 18 15)
            (16 19 20 17)
            (17 20 21 18)
        );
    }
);
// ************************************************************************* //
"""

# Clean comments:
test_str = re.sub(r"//.*", '', test_str)
test_str = re.sub(r"/\*.*?\*/", '', test_str, 0, re.DOTALL)

# Match main group
matches = re.findall(r"\bvertices\s*\((\s*(?:\([^)]+\)\s*)+)\)", test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

# Fetch tuples
matches2 = re.findall(r"\([^)]+\)", matches[0], re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
print matches2
```

**Explained:**

```
\b        # word boundary
vertices  # literal 'vertices'
\s*       # 0 or more spaces (includes line feed/carriage return)
\(        # literal '('
  (       # First capturing group
    \s*   # Som spaces
    (?:   # Group
       \([^)]+\)   # literal '(' + any non-')' character 1 or more times + literal ')'
       \s*         # extra spaces
    )+    # repeated one or more times
  )
\)        # literal ')'
```

Then you get that captured group and search for `\([^)]+\)`. That will find instances of vertices.

Comment: awesome. this works fine. the output is now a list of strings. how can you turn it into tuples? `(1 2 3 )` --> `(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: I edited the post, there are no `,`s between the numbers. just spaces. but your code works perfectly fine!

Comment: @Foad I changed my answer to allow comments. Also I tested it with the example file (plus extra comments). Please, note that the accepted answer will fail with the example file. See: https://ideone.com/9FzKVY this is because it matches tuples from other sections like `negY`, `posY`, `posYR` and `blocks`. If you are not supposed to match those, you may use this solution instead.

Comment: I just saw your edit. I will try it and come back here.

Comment: I was wondering if I could invite you to help us continue this?

Comment: Hi, how do you want to go on? Did you try with my last edit? Is there something missing?

Comment: Yes we indeed want to continue this to make a nice import package for FreeCAD. you may see it over [here](https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=30426&start=10#p251946). I haven't integrated your edits yet, but I will.

Comment: Oh, glad to hear that code from this question will be added to such a big opensource project. If you need something, just tell me

Comment: I will tell here the next steps if you don't mind: read the 8 integers inside the `()` after all `hex` keywords. put 4 points as a tuple `p1 , p2, p3 ,p4` so every hex ends up as two faces. `hex (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)` --> `[(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
vertices
(
    (1 2 3)
    (3 4 5)
    ...
)
```

add a [re.DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) as in

```
r1 = re.search(r'(?:vertices\s+)?(\([\w\s]+\))', s, re.DOTALL)
print r1.group(1)

>>> (1 2 3)
```

you may need to use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) if you want all results stored as a list as in

```
r1 = re.findall(r'(?:vertices\s+)?(\([\w\s]+\))', s, re.DOTALL)
print r1

>>> ['(1 2 3)', '(3 4 5)']
```

Comment: First regex does not seem to work. See here: https://regex101.com/r/VbE8RY/2/. Second regex could match things like `foobar ((1,2,3)(3))` instead of just `vertices ((1,2,3)(3))`. See: https://regex101.com/r/VbE8RY/3. Not sure if that could be a problem for OP, although

Comment: @Julio that is not the format OP is asking for. OP question is relating to tuples separated by a `,` hence the answer is still valid

Comment: @Tushortz my mistake. the format in the file has no `,`. edited the post. my apologies.

Comment: there are only spaces between the numbers

Comment: well, he said: *"I'm interested in is a list of tuples (xi yi zi)s of floats, between parentheses **after the vertices keyword**"* Anyways if there are no other possible keywords different than "vertices" on the file, then It is not necessary to check the vertices keyword anyways

Answer (score 1):

My test data file `blockMeshDict`:

```
vertices // comment 1
(
          (1 2 3) // comment 2
/* :) */  (3 4 5) /* multi line...
...comment */

          (65.71 72.8 2.0)
)
```

Code:

```
import re

with open("blockMeshDict", "r") as f:
    s=f.read()

# Remove comments like "//" until end of line
s = re.sub(r'//.*', '', s)

# Remove comments between /* and */
s = re.sub(r'/\*(.|\s)*?\*/', '', s, re.DOTALL)

r1 = re.search(r'vertices\s*\(\s*(.*)\s*\)', s, re.DOTALL)
vertices = [(float(v[0]),float(v[1]),float(v[2]))
        for v in re.findall(r'\(\s*([-0-9.]+)\s+([-0-9.]+)\s+([-0-9.]+)\s*\)', r1.group(1))]

print(vertices)
```

Output is the list of tuples (of float's):

```
[(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (3.0, 4.0, 5.0), (65.71, 72.8, 2.0)]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. while you were preparing this post I had to edit the OP because there was a mistake. there are no `,`s between the numbers. do you mind editing your post considering the input numbers as `(1 2 3)`?

Comment: Accepted your changes (with minor addition) in my answer.

Comment: there are a couple of other thing I would appreciate if you could add. first the tab or 4 spaces before tuples is optional. so it can be either `    (1 2 3)` or `(1 2 3)` or any other number of spaces.

Comment: also those numbers are floats not necessarily integers

Comment: It already prcesses any number of all kinds of whitespace before the vertex tuples, after "vertices", or before or after all parenthesis. (regex: \s+)

Comment: I found the issue. the spaces are ok. but because the actual numbers are floats, it ignores the ones with decimals. my bad.

Comment: Now reads the numbers as floats (but not read exponential notation  though)

Comment: awesome. it now imports my data perfectly.

Comment: is there any way to ignore anything in between `/* ... */`s and after `//...`? I need to remove comments from those files too.

Comment: I'm gonna test it. I also found [this website](https://regex101.com/) where you can try regexs

Comment: Edited to make multi-line /* comments */ work. This will be my last edit.

Comment: FYI the regex should be changed to `\(\s*([-0-9.]+)\s+([-0-9.]+)\s+([-0-9.]+)\s*\)` to include negative numbers.

Comment: Included negative numbers (and fixed multiline comment (once more)